# How i can ignore continuous log from shell command in jenkinsfile to move to next steps/stage?

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

Im running an emulator device inside docker container using jenkinsfile, one of the command is for launching the emulator and output is continuous streaming of log like the one below.

```
+ docker exec mycontainer emulator -avd pixel

emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextaudio: Could not init `pa' audio driver

emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037.....etc
```

Issue is jenkins keep waiting for this step to end however it will never end,
so how i can ignore the log and make jenkins move to next stage.

here is sample

```
stage('Building Docker') {
  steps {
     sh label: 'Creating Appium container', script: 'docker run --privileged -d -p 4750:4723 --name mycontainer amrka/ultimate:latest'
     sh label: 'Building Emulator', returnStdout: true(i try it with false as well), script: 'docker exec mycontainer emulator -avd pixel'
          }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `docker run` and put it in background, and use `docker logs <container>` to read the log stream?

Comment: could you elaborate more on the command i have mentioned above, as far as i know -p flag is used with docker run, but in my case im executing command inside the container itself

Comment: Now I'm less uncertain about the issue here, but seems like the issue is maybe with docker setup itself? Are you familiar with `entrypoint` and `cmd` in Docker? What I'd basically do is to start the thing with required params with `-d` to run it in bg, fire `docker logs` in another call (ensure first that service has already started) and then check the output if needed?

Comment: great thx, i will try that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by adding

emulator command inside shell script file and executing with -d flag as shown below

```
sh (label: 'Building Emulator', returnStdout: true, script: "docker exec -d --privileged ${containerName} bash -c './root/start_emu.sh'")
```